# Json.NET case-sensitive deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Is there a deserialization option to perform *case-sensitive* deserialization with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Suggest:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

must fail, when deserialized from:

```
{
  "email": "james@example.com",
  "active": true,
  "createdDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z",
  "roles": [
    "User",
    "Admin"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the failure? Mixing cases in variable names leads to maintenance nightmares months down the road

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not likely unfortunately.  It seems to be hardcoded to try case-sensitive then case-insensitive.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the closest matching <see cref="JsonProperty"/> object.
/// First attempts to get an exact case match of propertyName and then
/// a case insensitive match.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
/// <returns>A matching property if found.</returns>
public JsonProperty GetClosestMatchProperty(string propertyName)
{
    JsonProperty property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (property == null)
    {
        property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    return property;
}
```

[JsonPropertyCollection](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/11.0.2/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonPropertyCollection.cs#L132)

This is invoked by the internal reader so there's no simple switch that you could just flip.  It should be possible, but you would have to write the converter yourself to reject case-insensitive matches.

Comment: See also [Issue #815: Provide a way to do case-sensitive property deserialization](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/815) on github which requests the ability to opt-in to case sensitive deserialization with Json.NET.